# How to convert matrix table to tabular in C#

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

Hi my dear friends i have question about excel stuff in C#. I have matrix table in below image.

[image]

I have to convert it to tabular table with C# console like in below image.

[image]

Can you help me about it?

Comment: Where is your effort ?

Comment: I can read file with c# but i cannot editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I believe you want is an "unpivot."  Here is a very basic example, based on your sample data, of how you might unpivot this data using C# and Excel Interop:

```
Excel.Worksheet ws1 = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Worksheet ws2 = excel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[2];

int newRow = 5;

for (int col = 2; col <= 6; col++)
{
    string kalipTipi = ws1.Cells[4, 1].Value.ToString();
    string figur = ws1.Cells[5, col].Value.ToString();

    for (int row = 6; row <= 13; row++)
    {
        string ebat = ws1.Cells[row, 1].Value.ToString();
        Excel.Range r = ws2.Rows[string.Format("{0}:{0}", newRow++)];
        r.Cells[1, 1].Value = kalipTipi;
        r.Cells[1, 2].Value = figur;
        r.Cells[1, 3].Value = ebat;
        r.Cells[1, 4].Value = ws1.Cells[row, col].Value;
    }
}
```

Short of knowing what the rest of your worksheet looks like, it's hard to say how scalable this is, but it's at least a template for what you're trying to accomplish.